# State object.map() returning error - what am I overlooking?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, preact

I would appreciate a second pair of eyes on this...

The React Component is reading-in data from MariaDB within a useEffect(). The data is being read-in without error and a console.log displays the correct data (see image below).  In the `return()` section of the FunctionalComponent, I have this code:

```
<div class={style.tblBody}>
   {tableData !== undefined &&
      tableData.map((row: RDPresData) => {
         return `<div>${row.title}</div>`;
   })}
</div>
```

Here is the console error I receive *(note the logged data above the red error)*.

[image]

I'm sure that at 3:30am I am missing something obvious...

Comment: This part {tableData !== undefined && 

You have some if else checking and then map?

Comment: try with `tableData.tableData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your console.log output you can tell that `tableData` is an object, not an array. It says:

```js
{tableData: {...}}
```

If it was an array, it would say:

```js
{tableData: [...]}
```

For some reason, the `tableData` object happens to have numerical keys, like an array, but since it's not actually an array, `.map` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `console.log(tableData)` get above result. So you should get correctly object `tableData` and parse it to array to use `map`. Because map function is working for array.

Your `tableData` is an object. You should get values before use `map`.

```
<div class={style.tblBody}>
   {tableData?.tableData !== undefined &&
      Object.values(tableData.tableData).map((row: RDPresData) => {
         return `<div>${row.title}</div>`;
   })}
</div>
```